# Convert sql to mysqli_prepare with variable variables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having trouble to convert my code from sql to mysqli. $XX can be 1 or 0. When $XX=1 I want to search for it. When $XX=0, there must be no search for $XX. Same for $YY.

Old code

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE 1=1";    
if (!empty($XX)) {$sql .= " AND XX = 1 ";}    
if (!empty($YY)) {$sql .= " AND YY = 1 ";}
```

When $XX=1 and $YY=1, the code will look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE 1=1 AND XX = 1 AND YY = 1";
```

When $XX=0 and $YY=1, the code will look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE 1=1 AND YY = 1";
```

When $XX=0 and $YY=0, the code will look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE 1=1";
```

The 'problem' is that I do not want to search for XX=0 because that excludes all XX=1 answers. When XX=0, it should not search for XX.

New code

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE XX=? and YY=?");    
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $XX, $YY);
```

Who knows how the mysqli code must look like? Thanks!

Comment: is xx or yy user input?

Comment: @Chosen Wann Yes both $XX and $YY are user input.

Comment: Convert your code to PDO and you will have much less trouble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query in the following way

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (xx = ? OR ? = 0) AND (yy = ? OR ? = 0)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aba44/3)** demo

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (xx = ? OR ? = 0) AND (yy = ? OR ? = 0)";
$db = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $xx, $xx, $yy, $yy);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(...);
```

Comment: feasible but honestly, it's dirty .

Comment: whoow, that's quick thinking! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working, this saves me days!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Okay, from what I get now, it should be simple. If the only possible value for XX and YY in the query is 1, you don't need bind_param.

```
$qry = 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE 1=1';
$qry .= (!empty($XX)) ? ' AND XX=1';
$qry .= (!empty($YY)) ? ' AND YY=1';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $qry);
```

And then just execute your query.

Comment: You really need to rewrite mysql to mysqli at least once before trying to answer on such a transition

Comment: I'm not getting this. Explain?

Comment: This is the most simple part that you done. But there is also binding that you omit.

Comment: Well I don't see the use of bind in this query. There are no variables in the query, all condition values are 1 or non-existent. The only thing that I didn't put there was `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` after `mysql_prepare`. Can you provide the correct answer if I'm wrong?

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that question actually is much simpler than usual conditional binding. You don't need to prepare either, then.

Comment: However, that means that your answer is redundant, as it's actually just duplicate the code from the OP

Answer (score -1):

another alternate if you can pass the field name as parameter

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT name FROM tabel WHERE XX=? and YY=?");    
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $XX, $YY);
```

if you want to avoid filtering XX pass $XX as 'XX'(i.e field name) insted of 0

Answer (score -1):

In such a special case when no variable is actually going into query, you can stick to your current setup. Just change prepare and bind to mysqli_query().

However, in case you need to add a variable into query, you either can use peterm's  dirty solution or create the conditional query with placeholders and then call bind_param() with variable number of parameters using call_user_func_array()